# Reconcile Workspace for TFS 2015 vNext Builds

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

We used to get notification from the tray of our windows machine for a finished build while using the xaml build definitions, it also had an option to reconcile workspace. The same functionality is not available for the vNext builds.

The BuildNotification App is available with VS 2015, but it seems that the reconcile workspace is not available with the vNext build. Is there some other app that can give a notification and do the reconcile operation?

Answer (score 7):

We just moved to new builds (vNext) and are missing this feature as well. 
Currently, we can do this manually via IDE (VS 2015):

1. Team Explorer -> Builds
2. Right click on latest build with you changes ->  "Reconcile Workspace..."

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This is good enough for now because I typically reconcile long before the automatic popup from the build notification.

Answer (score 3):

The **BuildNotificationApp** is still a part of the VS 2015 and can be found here: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\BuildNotificationApp.exe`.  However, this app only applied to XAML build.

For now, to workaround the missing feature, you can use a free build status tool [Catlight](https://catlight.io/) . It also shows status of vNext builds in tray area.
[image]

As for reconcile workspace, there is no this build-in feature for vNext build. However, you can manually use [tf reconcile command](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg589719(v=vs.100).aspx) for your workspace. Such as below screenshot:
[image]

---

Update:

If you just want a simple app or vs extension to achieve it, there is no these things for now. You may have to customize your own extension to implement it.

---

Update2:

I have created a feature request in uservoice:

> **Reconcile Workspace for vNext Build**
>
> https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/15979690-reconcile-workspace-for-vnext-build

Comment: That's what I asked. I know we have the notification app available, but it does not provide a reconcile option. I can use catlight but I cannot everytime go and run a command to do a reconcile, rather I would use Visual Studio. But maybe I can create a app, based on TFS events and then try executing the reconcile from my app. I was asking for a more simpler out of box way to get notification and then reconcile from the notification itself, rather than running a command line.

Comment: Well, if you mean you just want a simple app or vs extension to achieve it, there is no these things for now.  You may have to customize your own extension to implement it.

Comment: okay, I'll try to create one, but it would be helpful if reconcile option is present for vNext builds with the build notifications app.

Comment: I have created a related feature request  in uservoice for  you. TFS PM will kindly review it and you can also vote up it. [Reconcile Workspace for vNext Build](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/15979690-reconcile-workspace-for-vnext-build)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AnyStatus](https://www.anystat.us) to monitor both vNext and XAML builds.
AnyStatus comes with a feature called Triggers which lets you run a program or a batch script in response to status changes. Using Triggers you can configure it to run "tf.exe reconcile" when the build status changes from Running to OK.

Disclaimer: I am the author of Any Status.

Comment: Nice! Its a good tool. I can store a command and run each time a build finishes.